# How to get a clean date In text with Core Data

Tags: objective-c

In my app I have a functionality which allows the user to select a certain date using the date picker. They then save their choice and I load it via a label in my DetailViewController.m. So far I have this code which displays the Date like this:

Month day, Year

Here is what I have so far

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[youOweData valueForKey:@"youOweDate"]];


[self.labelDueDate setText:formattedDateString];
```

If the user saved the date to be today's date the output would be:

**Feb 10, 2014**

***HOWEVER***

I would like to date to read:

**Monday February 10, 2014**

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle`. You should be using `NSDateFormatterFullStyle`.

See the docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDateFormatterStyle